# How to print date with underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

How do you print dates using `underscore.js`? I am surprised that there is apparently any way to do it unlike `ejs`

Here is what i would like to do

`<%= Message.created_at.getFullYear() %>-<%= Message.created_at.getMonth() + 1 %>-<%= Message.created_at.getDate() %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underscore's templates are (intentionally) simple and minimal so there aren't any built in formatting utilities. However, you can put whatever JavaScript expressions you want inside `<%= ... %>` so you can easily add your own formatting utilities. You could do something like this in your JavaScript:

```
window.fmt = {
    iso_date: function(d) {
        // Your favorite ISO 8601 date formatter goes here, this
        // is just a quick hack (which won't work in older IEs)
        // for demonstration purposes.
        return d.toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, '');
    },
    // Any other formatting functions you need go here...
};
```

and then call `fmt.iso_date` in your template thusly:

```
<%= fmt.iso_date(Message.created_at) %>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4Ufs4/